# JNA dll doesn't load with surefire plugin

Tags: maven, jna

My unit tests work in eclipse because the path to the DLL is set properly in jna.library.path.

But *mvn test* which uses the plugin fails with this error.

Unable to load library 'ehlapi32': Native library (win32-x86-64/ehlapi32.dll) not found in resource path

```
    <plugin><!-- This doesn't work -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
            <forkmode>never</forkmode>
             <argLine>-Djna.library.path=C:/my.dll</argLine>
           </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my *surefire* configuration that solved the problem. The particular DLL I was trying to load required a 32-bit JVM. So I specified that.

After this the DLL is found using one of the recommended approaches to load dll's using JNA.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
                <forkmode>once</forkmode>
                <jvm>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java</jvm>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```